# Why class variables are used for Django models?

Tags: django, models

First of all, I must declare that I'm quite new to Django.

I'm fine with creating simliar models like this one:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

However, I don't understand how django models works under the cover. What I did was specifying two class variables, when I say

```
person = Person();
person.first_name = 'abc'
```

Is the first_name I used in this code the same as the first_name I used in previous code? If yes first_name should be models.CharField, but I'm passing a string to it, how come it still works?

Answer (score 2):

Not a django guy, but this seems pretty standard... I'm not sure if I understood your question completely.

```
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Is declaring the field you are inputting the data into. Seems like youre creating a row in the "models" database.

```
person.first_name = 'abc'
```

Is simply filling in the first_name field for the instance of Person you created. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you are defining a class, and its class attributes.

In the second example, you create an instance of that class with `person = Person()` (drop the `;` it's not needed).

Then, the setter for a `model.CharField` accepts a string, it's still of type `CharField` though.

Comment: So you're saying the "first_name" I used in the second block the same as the "first_name" I used in first block? Isn't that one is class variable and the other is instance variables?

Comment: In the first, you're defining what instance attributes will be available. You're saying "a Person has a first name and a last name"  in the second, you're saying "make a new person", and then "this person's first name is 'abc'